# New Windows 11 "Memory Integrity" feature throws a blue screen of death with SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION citing NETIO.SYS

Tags: windows-11, bsod, memory-management

I've got a Dell Latitude 7320 with Windows 11, but I broke it after innocently turning on its Memory Integrity feature! It's some new feature that showed up on my Control Panel (or rather system Settings screen) tonight. I was led there by a new blue warning icon with a yellow exclamation tick that appeared at my bottom right system tray area:

[image]

That opened up a Settings screen that claimed that a security issue needed resolved:

[image]

It was a new legitimate Windows 11 feature that suggested it offered better process memory protection and required a restart.

[image]

But now I'm stuck in a neverending blue screen of death cycle that keeps recurring upon reboot. I've learned through this also that Windows 11 does not have a Safe Mode (or I was simply unable to reach it). I'm sure the recurring BSOD is a result of me turning on this new feature. How can I recover from this?

Comment: Windows 11 has Safe Mode. It may not be working for you for some reason.  I think you are talking about Core Isolation. That does not work on any of my (new) Windows 11 Pro machines.   Try updating BIOS and Drivers with the computer manufacturer's Driver Update App. You may be able to do this using bootable USB.

Comment: Is safe mode holding down the Shift key? Not working for me. And wouldn't the bootable USB need to have been made by Windows 11? I don't have another Windows 11 machine in the house. This is all just very inconvenient. I'll figure out a way to get a bootable USB but this issue should have been prevented somehow and I shouldn't have to know how as an average user. This slipped through the cracks at QA either at Microsoft or Dell, my laptop manufacturer.

Comment: Try restarting and pressing F8 repeatedly to get into Safe Mode. I am not certain what is wrong with your machine but Safe Mode works - tested here.

Comment: I suppose I would have to hold down the FN key to hit F8 but it's not working either. Tried it without the FN key as well.

Comment: You may need to reinstall Windows with the Dell Recovery media or Recovery partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems that there is no way to recover at this point back into Windows 11, the next best idea I found is to try pressing F12 repeatedly upon a cold boot and enter the One Time Boot Menu, per https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-au/000177401/restore-your-system-using-dell-supportassist-os-recovery. There's a BIOS and Firmware Update Over the Air option here. I ran it, and it connected to my Wi-Fi and checked for updates, but it said my BIOS is already up to date. Next I had to continue cold booting again repeatedly pressing the F12 key to get back to that One Time Boot Menu and launch Dell SupportAssist OS Recovery. From here I was able to run hardware scans which found no significant issues. Ultimately reinstalling Windows using the reset options here was my only viable recourse, since launching Windows 11 seemed completely impossible after that new process memory protection feature was activated.

Comment: I should add that the Dell menus will require your BitLocker key, accessible through https://account.microsoft.com/devices/recoverykey?refd=support.microsoft.com. Also, a very useful part of the menus here on the Dell machine was the ability to backup my files to an external USB drive before starting to reset Windows.

Comment: It's July 2023. I'd like to provide an update to this and ask whether others have resolved it differently: The benefit of Memory Integrity for me will be much higher protection against malicious threats to my OS. Back when I performed the Dell SupportAssist OS Recovery in Sept. 2022, it brought me back to Win10--which ran great. However, now I'm back to Win11, and the same Memory Integrity feature has been suggested again by the OS. My Dell BIOS seems to be 1.24.2 Should I try turning on Memory Integrity again, or am I at risk of getting another BSOD? I'm checking myself, but thought I'd ask.